# Tapestry 5 - How can I do client-side 'required' validation on <t:radiogroup>?

Tags: java, validation, tapestry

I need to validate, on the **client**, whether one of the radio buttons in a `<t:radioGroup>` has been selected on form submission.

Using the standard `t:validate="required"` attribute like so does not work

```
<t:radiogroup t:id="options" value="data.options" t:validate="required" >
    <t:label for="option1"/><t:radio t:id="option1" t:value="option1"/>
    <t:label for="option2"/><t:radio t:id="option2" t:value="option2"/>
</t:radiogroup>
```

N.B. it *is* possible to do this server-side using the standard `validate="required"` attribute - but again I need this client-side.

It seems odd that the standard server-side required validation works but the standard client-side required validation doesn't work for the `<t:radiogroup>` component.

How else can I achieve this on the client-side?

Comment: +1, I thought this is how it should work !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, this is something you have to implement yourself. If there is not already an issue about this, you should feel free to add one to Tapestry's JIRA.